Pinning/fixing the order of the languages (input sources / keyboard layouts) on macOS
I'm wondering if there's a way to control the order of languages used on my Mac.
The Problem:
As you can see in the screenshot, I regularly use four languages: English (EN), Turkish (TR), Russian (RU), and Turkmen (TM). Unfortunately, the order of these languages keeps changing chaotically in three places:

The menu bar
The on-screen input source selector
The keyboard settings window

The Issue:
Unlike Windows, where you can set a preferred language order that stays consistent everywhere, macOS seems to randomize the order. This makes it difficult to quickly switch between languages by muscle memory like I can on Windows (where my preferred order is EN, TR, RU, TM).
Why It Matters:
While this might not be an issue for users with just one or two languages, having to constantly search for the desired language among four or more options slows down my workflow.
What I've Tried:
I've searched extensively in System Preferences and other settings, but there seems to be no option to change or pin the order of languages.
I try to memorise the order of the languages but the order constantly changes, so memorising is not a solution at all.
My Setup:

Macbook Pro 14 (2024) M2 Max.
Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)

What I'm Looking For:
I'm not interested in apps that assign specific languages to individual programs. I'd simply like to set a preferred order for all languages that remains consistent across the entire system.
I hope this explanation is clear. Any suggestions on how to achieve this on macOS would be greatly appreciated!


"having to constantly search for the desired language among four or more options slows down my workflow" - is it really root problem here? In order to be true one must be touch typist in all four keyboard layouts and switching from one language to another in one's head and fingers must be instantaneous. Regarding order: this is not randomized but ordered by last usage. So previous input source ctrl-space.  Language prior to that ctrl-space-space etc.

I have to do now as you say (ctrl-space-space) but you see it's not practical when you get used to Windows where you know that in double click from English, you get to Russian, from triple to Turkish, double to Turkmen and vice versa. Here on Mac I have to memorise what 2-3 last used languages were and switch accordingly and if I miss a click or click more, the order renews. That isn't very pleasant, you know. I want to switch keys without looking at the screen like on Windows.

I don't ask Mac developers to rewrite the code, just adding a pinning feature (by default disabled) will not affect old-school mac users at all.

Probably I miss something but isn’t looking at screen what touch typist do?  Not looking at the keyboard, not looking at the screen - what do you look at then?

Well, the issue is not in looking at something. I look both at the screen and keyboard while typing.
The thing is that when you have 4 languages, it's not easy to remember when you used last time the next desired keyboard because the order of the languages changes according to the last used one, right?
So, when I need to switch, I operate with two keyboards (on my Bluetooth keyboard: Ctrl + Space, unlike on native kb either with only Fn, or the same combination) by holding Ctrl and pressing Space until getting to the needed one.

And it's frustrating when you miss the bus-stop, you have to start the journey again, and if you pause, or leave Space, the order changes again.
Please, try adding 4 languages on your keyboard and you will understand me better. Or even better, try 4 languages both o macOS and Windows, you will feel the difference with your soul.

On Windows, I know that the order En, Tr, Ru, Tm won't change so even if I mischanged the language, I can easily get to the necessary one without worrying that the order will change, no matter how fast I change (because on Mac, If you pause, or leave Space and want to change again, the order now will be new)
